# Tree node to support browser compatibility

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I am currently working on an application page which works only for IE browser.The page contains a tree node which loads the data with single selection checkbox.

Code in JSP Page :

```
<xml id=TheCodes>
<%=codesXML%>
</xml>
          <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td align=left valign=top colspan="5">
<script language="JavaScript">
    loadcodes(10,'codesTable','#TheCodes',' ' ,'desc','<%=compositeDescTagName%>','<%=compositeDescFormName%>','<%=codeFormName%>','<%=codeIdFormName%>','document.resourceform.<%=Globals.ENFORCE_COMMENTS%>');
</script>
```

The reference will be to a javascript page

```
function loadcodes(depth,tableId,dataSrc,onclickfunc,descFld,compositeDescTagName,compositeDescFormName,codeFormName,codeIdFormName,enforceCommentsFormName)
{
    document.writeln("<TABLE height=100% id=PrimaryTable dataSrc='" + dataSrc + "' cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0> <TBODY>");
    writeNode(depth,dataSrc,descFld,compositeDescTagName,compositeDescFormName,codeFormName,codeIdFormName,enforceCommentsFormName);
    document.writeln("</TBODY></TABLE>");
}

function writeNode(depth,dataSrc,descFld,compositeDescTagName,compositeDescFormName,codeFormName,codeIdFormName,enforceCommentsFormName)
{
    if (depth <= 0)
        return;
    document.writeln("<TR onclick=\"toggle(this,'" + dataSrc + "','" + compositeDescTagName + "','" + compositeDescFormName + "','" + codeFormName + "','" + codeIdFormName + "','" + enforceCommentsFormName + "')\" class=tree_indent>");
        document.writeln("<TD><IMG dataFld='image' id=Icon class=tree_node>");
    document.writeln("<SPAN dataFld=" + descFld + " class=formtext></SPAN>");
    document.writeln("<SPAN dataFld=haschildren id=HasChildren style='DISPLAY:none'></SPAN><SPAN dataFld=isleaf id=isleaf style='DISPLAY: none'></SPAN><SPAN dataFld=composite_desc id=composite_desc style='DISPLAY:none'></SPAN>");
    document.writeln("<SPAN dataFld=composite_code id=composite_code style='DISPLAY:none'></SPAN>");
    document.writeln("<SPAN dataFld=composite_id id=composite_id style='DISPLAY:none'></SPAN>");
    document.writeln("<SPAN dataFld=comments_required id=comments_required style='DISPLAY:none'></SPAN>");
    document.writeln("</TD></TR>");
    document.writeln("<TR style='DISPLAY: none' class=tree_indent>");
        document.writeln("<TD><!-- next level -->");
        document.writeln("<TABLE class=tree_node id=node dataFld=node valign=top border=0 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 >");
        document.writeln("<TBODY>");
    writeNode(--depth,dataSrc,descFld,compositeDescTagName,compositeDescFormName,codeFormName,codeIdFormName,enforceCommentsFormName);
        document.writeln("</TBODY>");
        document.writeln("</TABLE>");
        document.writeln("</TD>");
        document.writeln("</TR>");
}

var selectedCode;
function toggle(e,dataSrc,compositeDescTagName,compositeDescFormName,codeFormName,codeIdFormName,enforceCommentsFormName)
{
  var nextRow;
  var nextRow1;

  nextRow = e.nextSibling;

  hc = e.all.HasChildren;
  var isleaf = e.all.isleaf;

    if (nextRow.style.display == "none" && isleaf.innerText == "false")
    {
        nextRow.style.display = "";
        e.all.Icon.src = "/edcs/images/minus.gif";

        if (nextRow.all && nextRow.all[2] && !nextRow.all[2].dataSrc) 
        {
            nextRow.all[2].dataSrc = dataSrc;
        }
    } 
    else if (isleaf.innerText == "true")
    {
        // reset the bullet on the one already selected
        if (selectedCode && selectedCode.all && selectedCode.all.Icon)
            selectedCode.all.Icon.src = "/edcs/images/bullet.gif";

        e.all.Icon.src = "/edcs/images/right.gif";

        re=/'/g;

        var str = e.all.composite_desc.innerText.replace(re,"\\'");

        eval(compositeDescTagName + ".innerText = '"  + str + "'");
        eval(compositeDescFormName + ".value = '"  + str + "'");
        eval(codeFormName + ".value = '"  + e.all.composite_code.innerText + "'");
        eval(codeIdFormName + ".value = '"  + e.all.composite_id.innerText + "'");
        commentsEnforced = eval(enforceCommentsFormName + ".value");
        if (commentsEnforced == "false")
            eval(enforceCommentsFormName + ".value = '"  + e.all.comments_required.innerText + "'");

        selectedCode = e;
    }
    else
    {
        nextRow.style.display = "none";
        e.all.Icon.src = "/edcs/images/plus.gif";
    }
}
```

I am aware that Datasrc , Datafld are not supported by other browsers.Is there any alternative way to create the same tree node  or any modifications to be made on the exisitng code to support different browsers.

Kindly help me out ...

Answer (score 0):

It's funny that you tag your question with Jquery as that is where the answer lies, in particular have a look at jquery.treeTable.js which works fines even on IE8 see http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/

A quick sample would be something like

```
<table>
  <tr data-tt-id="1">
    <td>Parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-tt-id="2" data-tt-parent-id="1">
    <td>Child</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ user2310289 Thanks for your reply.Btw i have been trying with Jquery plugins also.But my question is to load the data dynamically based on the drop down list selection.If you have used the above plugin , can u kindly explain how it fits into my scenario.In my case i am passing the dynamic values to the function , How can it be done here ..